# How to read a Variable from a file in LATEX?

Tags: environment-variables

How to read a variable from a file, lets say textfile `var.txt` that contains the following:

```
foo = 10
bar = 20
```

Now I am looking for a command `\missingcommand` that scans the file and it can be used in my Latex code like this:

```
The first value \missingcommand{foo} and the second value \missingcommand{bar}.
```

Compiles to:

```
The first value 10 and the second value 20.
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated

Answer (score 21):

This uses my `readarray` package.  It relies on there being space separators between fields, and exactly 3 fields in each row: `<variable> = <value>`.  See **ADDENDUM** for improved version.

EDITED (12/2016) to use preferred syntax of upgraded `readarray` package, namely, `\MyDat[\arabic{datacount},3]` in lieu of deprecated `\arrayij{MyDat}{\arabic{datacount}}{3}`. Likewise, `\readarray\data\MyDat[-,3]` in lieu of `\readArrayij{\data}{MyDat}{3}`.

Note also that `\value{datacount}` of original answer was necessarily revised to `\arabic{datacount}`, as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
foo = 10
bar = 20
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand\missingcommand[1]{\csname DATA#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\readdef{mydata.dat}{\data}
\readarray\data\MyDat[-,3]
\MyDatROWS{} rows of data read.

\newcounter{datacount}
\setcounter{datacount}{0}%
\whiledo{\value{datacount} < \MyDatROWS}{%
  \stepcounter{datacount}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname DATA\MyDat[\arabic{datacount},1]\endcsname{%
    \MyDat[\arabic{datacount},3]}%
}

The first value \missingcommand{foo} and the second value \missingcommand{bar}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

Note that with latest `readarray` package version, the field separator can be set to other characters or strings.  Thus, for this application, it would be preferable to set the field separator as the `=` character (using `\readarraysepchar{=}`), so that spaces around the `=` sign are not a requirement.  Then, using the starred version of the new/improved `\readarray`, leading/trailing spaces can be excised automatically from the data.  Thus, the best version of the above code, producing identical results, can be given as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}[2016-11-07]
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
foo = 10
bar=20
\end{filecontents*}
\newcommand\missingcommand[1]{\csname DATA#1\endcsname}
\readarraysepchar{=}
\begin{document}
\readdef{mydata.dat}{\data}
\readarray*\data\MyDat[-,2]
\MyDatROWS{} rows of data read.

\newcounter{datacount}
\setcounter{datacount}{0}%
\whiledo{\value{datacount} < \MyDatROWS}{%
  \stepcounter{datacount}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname DATA\MyDat[\arabic{datacount},1]\endcsname{%
    \MyDat[\arabic{datacount},2]}%
}

The first value \missingcommand{foo} and the second value \missingcommand{bar}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18):

You could use `datatool`. Its made for database structures inside LaTeX. I use this in a similar context as you like to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool, filecontents}
\DTLsetseparator{ = }% Set the separator between the columns. Could be
% anything you like. Whitespaces are not trimmed, so you have to set
%them as part of the separator.

\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
foo = 10
bar = 20
"x" = 30
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={thekey,thevalue}]{mydata}{mydata.dat}
% Loads mydata.dat with column headers 'thekey' and 'thevalue'

\newcommand{\missingcommand}[1]{\DTLfetch{mydata}{thekey}{#1}{thevalue}}

The first value \missingcommand{foo} and the second value \missingcommand{bar}.

\end{document}
```

If `thekey` is a single character, it has to be sourrounded by quotation marks.

[image: Read Values]

Comment: I was waiting for someone to post a `datatool` solution. +1

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if `thekey` is only one character.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: If `thekey` is only one character, you have to place it between quotation marks, e.g. `"f" = 10`. I have to say that I do not really now why you have to do it.