# Working with large data table

Tags: tables

In my research, I usually have to deal with large table of results. I try to find a way to import these results into Latex. I search the internet and try some package like csvsimple, pgfplotstable. At first, these packages work with small table of 3, 4 rows and columns. However, when I add more rows and more columns, the packages won't work anymore. With larger table dimension, there are many errors with floating point number, taking the message below as an example: 
***"! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '(-1.63)' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '(-1.63)'."***
Does someone have the solution to this problem. I attach an example of what I am working below. The data is in text format, with comma separator.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,pgfplots,booktabs,filecontents,pdflscape,
csvsimple,longtable}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{result3.dat}
model,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10
fdcexp,0.402**,,,,,0.402**,,,,
,-2.19,,,,,-2.19,,,,
L.gdpper,-0.00472,-0.00465,-0.00540***,-0.00542***,-0.00540***,-0.00472,-0.00465,-0.00540***,-0.00542***,-0.00540***
,(-1.63),(-1.60),(-3.45),(-3.45),(-3.44),(-1.63),(-1.60),(-3.45),(-3.45),(-3.44)
growth,0.138,0.149,0.0726,0.0794,0.0868,0.138,0.149,0.0726,0.0794,0.0868
,-0.29,-0.32,-0.18,-0.2,-0.22,-0.29,-0.32,-0.18,-0.2,-0.22
D.lnhuman,-0.533,-0.496,-0.639,-0.661,-0.622,-0.533,-0.496,-0.639,-0.661,-0.622
,(-0.60),(-0.55),(-0.90),(-0.93),(-0.88),(-0.60),(-0.55),(-0.90),(-0.93),(-0.88)
ligdp,-0.251,-0.238,-0.148,-0.135,-0.148,-0.251,-0.238,-0.148,-0.135,-0.148
,(-1.55),(-1.49),(-0.58),(-0.53),(-0.58),(-1.55),(-1.49),(-0.58),(-0.53),(-0.58)
fdcall,,0.400**,,,,,0.400**,,,
,,-2.21,,,,,-2.21,,,
fdcave,,,0.0626*,,,,,0.0626*,,
,,,-2.06,,,,,-2.06,,
fdcnet,,,,0.0262**,,,,,0.0262**,
,,,,-2.2,,,,,-2.2,
fdcrev,,,,,0.0643***,,,,,0.0643***
,,,,,-3,,,,,-3
yr2007,,,,,,3.495***,3.495***,3.416***,3.398***,3.430***
,,,,,,-9.26,-9.27,-6.02,-5.97,-5.98
_cons,8.796***,8.526***,7.695**,7.575**,7.678**,8.796***,8.526***,7.695**,7.575**,7.678**
,-4.23,-4.17,-2.25,-2.21,-2.25,-4.23,-4.17,-2.25,-2.21,-2.25
N,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259,259
r2_o,0.152,0.131,0.187,0.181,0.185,0.152,0.131,0.187,0.181,0.185
\end{filecontents}
\begin{landscape}
\centering\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.2pt}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
display columns/0/.style={string type,,string replace*={_}{\_},column type={l}},
columns/modelx/.style={string type},
]{result3.dat}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image: I would like my table to look like this]

Comment: what does "won't work anymore" mean? do you get a TeX error? if so show the exact error that you get, also preferably show an example document that allows the error to be reproduced so it can be debugged.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321346/how-to-read-a-variable-from-a-file-in-latex perhaps?  The answers employ packages like `readaray` and `datatool`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I added the code that I used with the data.

Comment: Do you need merely to "import" the data (subsequently accessible by row,column entry), or do you need to process and render the complete array in `tabular` form?

Comment: the posted code doesn't give the error in your question but `! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '0.402**' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '**'..` isn't this the same error message as your last question,  `0.402**` wouldn't be a valid floating point number in most languages

Comment: If I remove the `*` I get  `! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '(-1.63)' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '(-1.63)'..`  so if I remove the `()` I get  `! Missing $ inserted.` so if I chnage `_` to `\_` then your document runs without error so there is nothing to suggest it is a problem with large data sets just that your entries are not simple numbers so you need to clean up or filter the data before plotting

Comment: do you just want to make a table or are you going to need to plot the data (if just typesetting a table you don't need pgfplotstable)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I uploaded the format of the table I would like to make from these data. As you can see, the table would have *** and other characters, even a math formula. Do you have any idea I could add these character into the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of minutes editing makes something that can be typeset as a table. Your use of the `pgfplotstable` package implies tex needs to treat the data as numeric values in which case more filtering would be necessary.

here I just changed `,` to `&` and added `\\` at ends of lines,

It is still over full but before shrinking the fonts and other things do you need so many decimal places, values like -0.00540 make it hard to show reasonable table. You could format these numbers in tex but probably simpler to do that in whatever application is outputting this data.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape,longtable,array,dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setlength\LTleft{-10pt}
\setlength\LTright{-10pt plus 1fill}
\begin{longtable}{@{}l*{10}{D..{3.6}}@{}}
model&-1&-2&-3&-4&-5&-6&-7&-8&-9&-10\\
fdcexp&0.402**&&&&&0.402**&&&&\\
&-2.19&&&&&-2.19&&&&\\
L.gdpper&-0.00472&-0.00465&-0.00540***&-0.00542***&-0.00540***&-0.00472&-0.00465&-0.00540***&-0.00542***&-0.00540***\\
&(-1.63)&(-1.60)&(-3.45)&(-3.45)&(-3.44)&(-1.63)&(-1.60)&(-3.45)&(-3.45)&(-3.44)\\
growth&0.138&0.149&0.0726&0.0794&0.0868&0.138&0.149&0.0726&0.0794&0.0868\\
&-0.29&-0.32&-0.18&-0.2&-0.22&-0.29&-0.32&-0.18&-0.2&-0.22\\
D.lnhuman&-0.533&-0.496&-0.639&-0.661&-0.622&-0.533&-0.496&-0.639&-0.661&-0.622\\
&(-0.60)&(-0.55)&(-0.90)&(-0.93)&(-0.88)&(-0.60)&(-0.55)&(-0.90)&(-0.93)&(-0.88)\\
ligdp&-0.251&-0.238&-0.148&-0.135&-0.148&-0.251&-0.238&-0.148&-0.135&-0.148\\
&(-1.55)&(-1.49)&(-0.58)&(-0.53)&(-0.58)&(-1.55)&(-1.49)&(-0.58)&(-0.53)&(-0.58)\\
fdcall&&0.400**&&&&&0.400**&&&\\
&&-2.21&&&&&-2.21&&&\\
fdcave&&&0.0626*&&&&&0.0626*&&\\
&&&-2.06&&&&&-2.06&&\\
fdcnet&&&&0.0262**&&&&&0.0262**&\\
&&&&-2.2&&&&&-2.2&\\
fdcrev&&&&&0.0643***&&&&&0.0643***\\
&&&&&-3&&&&&-3\\
yr2007&&&&&&3.495***&3.495***&3.416***&3.398***&3.430***\\
&&&&&&-9.26&-9.27&-6.02&-5.97&-5.98\\
\_cons&8.796***&8.526***&7.695**&7.575**&7.678**&8.796***&8.526***&7.695**&7.575**&7.678**\\
&-4.23&-4.17&-2.25&-2.21&-2.25&-4.23&-4.17&-2.25&-2.21&-2.25\\
N&259&259&259&259&259&259&259&259&259&259\\
r2\_o&0.152&0.131&0.187&0.181&0.185&0.152&0.131&0.187&0.181&0.185\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```